# verbose name on class field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am need of help to add a verbose name.

```
class Address(models.Model) :
    
    class Zip(models.Field):
       def db_type(self, connection):
           return 'char(8)'

    zip            = Zip()
    address        = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Rua")

        .....
```

Need put the verbose name of ZIP to CEP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django **[`models.Field.__init__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass)** takes **[`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name)** as parameter you can set name there

```
class Address(models.Model):

    class Zip(models.Field):

        def __init__(self, max_length=8, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs['verbose_name'] = "Zip code"
            self.max_length = max_length
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def deconstruct(self):
            name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
            del kwargs["verbose_name"]
            if kwargs.get("max_length"):
               del kwargs["max_length"]
            return name, path, args, kwargs

        def db_type(self, connection):
            return 'char(%s)' % self.max_length

    zip = Zip()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Rua")
```

From **[Django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction)**

> The counterpoint to writing your **init**() method is writing the
> deconstruct() method. It’s used during model migrations to tell Django
> how to take an instance of your new field and reduce it to a
> serialized form - in particular, what arguments to pass to **init**()
> to re-create it.
>
> If you haven’t added any extra options on top of the field you
> inherited from, then there’s no need to write a new deconstruct()
> method. If, however, you’re changing the arguments passed in
> **init**() (like we are in HandField), you’ll need to supplement the values being passed.

Comment: Hello @CarlosRocha if you've custom fields it is recomended that when you create it then one should set [deconstruction()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction) method

Comment: Got it But if it was (return 'char(value)') at the time of return instead of return 'char(8)', if so, could I do something like zip = Zip(8) somehow?

Comment: No, you've hardcoded value but it can be I'll update my answer

Comment: Hello @CarlosRocha check I've updated my answer now you can add `zip = Zip(8)` or `zip = Zip(255)` any values

Comment: error:   File "D:\Softwares\python\dj\hotplateprensas\address\models.py", line 14, in deconstruct
    del kwargs["max_length"]
KeyError: 'max_length'

Comment: i did so zip            = Zip(8)

Comment: Remove `del kwargs["max_length"]` from `deconstruct()` method

Comment: TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field zip on address.Address: Zip.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'max_length'

Comment: Hello @CarlosRocha check I've updated my answer added default value to 8 in `Zip()` and added one check inside `deconstruct()` method.

Comment: then, now cant create the table on the database mysql therefore the migations files yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247248/discussion-between-ankit-tiwari-and-carlos-rocha).